# Normal subgroups of prosupersolvable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite supersolvable group, and if $p$ is the biggest prime dividing $\vert G \vert$. Then $G$ has normal subgroups of order every possible power of $p$.

Analogous statement in case of profinite:
Let $G$ be a prosupersolvable group such that only finitely many primes divide $\vert G \vert$ and let $p$ be the biggest among them. Let $\vert G \vert = sp^m$, where s is a supernatural number and $p$ does not divide $s$. Does $G$ have normal closed subgroups of index $sp^k, 0 \leq k \leq m$.

My idea is to construct an inverse limit of normal subgroups of order $p^t, 0 \leq t \leq m-k$ of $\{G_i\}_{i\in I}$ where $G_i$'s are finite continuous quotient of $G$. But I am unable to make these normal subgroups an inverse system.

Can we extend it to arbitrary prosupersolvable group?